# Laravel: How to Filter In Custom GetAttribute Before Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am able to filter the `Custom Get Attribute` field after retrieving it to the `collection`. I now need to filter before using `get()`

Example:

For `is_paid` custom attribute

```
//is_paid
public function getIsPurchasedAttribute()
{
    //Since purchased has one relation with user
    return !empty($this->purchasedRelation) ? true : false;
}
```

I now need to retrieve `User` based on is_purchased like:

```
public function index(Request $request){
        $isPaid = $request->is_paid;

        $users = User::query();

        if($isPaid){
            $users = $users->where('is_paid', true);

        }

        $users = $users->paginate(10);

        return view('user.index', [
            'users' => $users
        ]);

    }
```

If I do like this, it will return:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'is_paid' in 'where clause

Yes, I can do like but I am now unable to use `paginate` function:

```
$users = User::get();

$users = $users->where('is_paid', 1);

return view('user.index', [
    'users' => $users
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody stumbles upon the same error and for future reference, I am posting the method I used to solve the problem:

The created custom getAttribute can be obtained only after retrieving the model.

That is using `first()` or `find()`

You cannot filter in the query collection.

So in order to filter only `is_paid` attribute; I first retrieved the collection of model and filtered afterwards like:

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $isPaid = $request->is_paid;

    $users = User::get();

    if($isPaid){
        $users = $users->where('is_paid', true);

    }

    $users = $users->paginate(10);

    return view('user.index', [
        'users' => $users
    ]);

}
```

In order to use pagination for collection, I followed [Gist For Paginated Collections In Laravel](https://gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e)

Answer (score 0):

You can return all users that have purchases by using the `whereHas()` method.

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $users = User::query();

    if ($request->is_paid) {
        $users->whereHas('purchasedRelation');
    }

    return view('user.index', [
        'users' => $users->paginate(10),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: The logic is little bit more. And I dont want to duplicate the code.

Comment: Why do you think you will duplicate code? What other logic does it have?